# Polymer animation get Keyframes error

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-animations

I have created a simple animation for my elements, but instead of cool effects I get `Uncaught TypeError: Keyframes must be null or an array of keyframes`.

```
<script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'marvin-user-entrance',
            behaviors: [
                Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
            ],
            properties: {
                animationConfig: {
                    value: function() {
                        return {
                            'fade-in':[{name: 'fade-in-animation', node: this}],
                            'fade-out':[{name: 'fade-out-animation', node: this}]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            animate: function () {
                this.playAnimation('fade-out');
            },
            ready: function () {
                this.$.auth.animate();
            }
        });

    </script>
```

It seems that it's not a problem of Polymer itself, but it is somewhere in my code or web animation node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `this.animate()` instead of `this.$.auth.animate()` as the `animate` function is defined inside *this Polymer element*.

If you want to animate the *auth* element only, change the `node` to point to `this.$.auth` instead of the whole element, like below -

```
node: this.$.auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is the root of this but I found that similar errors go away after setting the width and height of the animated element explicitly in CSS in pixels.